# Building an External JavaScript Reference Using a local script in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have around 45-50 unique javascripts that contain data to be used in a graph. I do not want to link every single one of them. Is there a way to create a single external reference tag and fill it with a string i create in the local java inside the HTML? That way it can update at my leisure and I don't have to external reference 50 unique scripts at any given time. Note this is not on a server strictly local only for now. Also, I have only been using javascript and HTML a couple of weeks so I am a novice.

I have tried to create a tag inside the script link such as:

```
<script id="builtstringreference"></script>
```

but it produces nothing.

I have built the string that references the external javascript but can not get it back to the external reference link.

What I have in HTML:

```
   <script id="trial"></script>
```

What I have in local Javascript:

```
    var txt1 = document.getElementById("Product").value;
    var txt2 = document.getElementById("Reactor").value;
    var trialchange = "../Lot Data Trial Folder/lotdata_"+txt1+"_"+txt2+".js"
    document.getElementById("trial").innerHTML=trialchange;
    window.alert(trialchange); //just for testing
    window.alert(typeof(trialchange)); //just for testing
```

What I want it to look like after update:

```
<script src="an external j.s"></script>
```

That way the external j.s can be changed and updated at any time without preloading 50 external j.s

I expect that I can change the external file at any time by selecting new product combos from drop-down lists which update ```txt1 and txt2 which builds the new external reference string but I feel like it's not this easy.

Comment: Remove this line:  document.getElementById("trial").innerHTML=trialchange and add this line: document.getElementById("trial").setAttribute('src', trialchange);   

It should add attribute src to html tag, not add content into that element.

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks! I knew there had to be a way to avoid writing 50 external references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something like build and then destroy the script tag

```
function createjs(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.addEventListener('load', function(){ resolve(); });
    script.id = 'id-scr1';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src='assets/script.js'
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}

createjs();

function removeJS(id){
    document.getElementById( id ).remove();
}

removeJS('id-scr1');
```